# How to change background colors in ReadOnly textbox in silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I Want To Change Color of ReadOnly Textbox

It is Possible To Change Default Color to **white Color**

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Black"/>
        </Style>
```

and textbox as

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="18" Padding="0" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="3,0,3,0"/>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: yes i Check This Link With I am Note Able To Change Color as white

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not that the Background Setter doesn't work, it is that the ReadOnly state for the TextBox has a gray overlay.

There are two options here:

1. Edit the control template for the TextBox in Expression Blend, and get rid of the overlay.
2. Set **IsReadOnly** to **false** and set **IsHitTestVisible** to **false**, this will prevent editting of the TextBox without changing its Visual State.

Comment: Thnks For Reply But When i Set IsHitTextVisible = true and IsReadOnly =false then Is's Editable Textbox but i Dont want to give Editable Textbox

Comment: If IsHitTestVisible is false the TextBox cannot be focused, and therefore cannot be edited...

Comment: Thanks man.. You just saved me from a good old hassle with xaml + c#