# background for a ReadOnly TextBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I set the background for a ReadOnly TextBox?

And a second question:
I want to start developing apps for my Windows Phone. But at the moment I only will use them on my own phone. Do I have to register with Microsoft to install my apps on my phone?

Comment: Doesn't `textBox.BackColor(...)` work?

Comment: Please, do not ask multiple independant questions in one post.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700272/how-to-change-background-colors-in-readonly-textbox-in-silverlight-5

Comment: First question is answered by minimal research which you should do for yourself. Second question is off topic.  Please check the [help] before asking another question.

Comment: I only can have textBox.Background(..) not textBox

Comment: I only have textBox.Background(...) not textBox.BackColor(..).

Comment: Sorry for the errors. Background is not working. The Box is still gray. And with writeBox.IsHitTestVisible=false; I can't scroll the writeBox.

Answer (score 0):

**Question One:**
There are multiples way to set background color

1. Set Background in xaml Manually as follow

   ```
   <TextBox x:Name="txtbox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="Teal" Text="TextBox" IsReadOnly="True" />
   ```
2. Set at run time.

   ```
   SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush();
   color.Color = (Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0xFF, 44, 50, 50));
   txtbox.Background = color;
   ```
3. change background from property explorer.

**Second Question:** 
Yes you need to create developer account. which is free of cost if you don't want to publish. After that you also need to unlock your phone for development and that you can do with windows phone developer registration utility; available at **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\Phone Registration"**. if you have already install windows phone sdk.

1. plug your phone
2. run registration utility
3. login with developer account
4. register it and enjoy coding

Comment: In the line
  color.Color = (Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0xFF, 44, 50, 50)); 
Error 
Cannot implicity convert type Windows.UI.Color tp ‘System.Windows.Media.Color’

I use Windows phone Silverlight
(Don’t know why, can I skip Siverlight on an easy way?)

Then I used a style
<SolidColorBrush x:Key=”snowbrush” Color”Snow” /> 

And in the c# code 
 myWriteBox.Background =snowbrush; 
This has no effect.

I can do 
 myWriteBox.isRadOnly = false;
 myWriteBox.isHitTestVisible = false; 

But then I cannot scroll the TextBox.

Thanks for answering the secod question it helped me a lot

Comment: try this  `color.Color = (new  Windows.UI.ColorHelper.FromArgb(0xFF, 44, 50, 50));`

Comment: Then I get the error Windows.UI.Clorhelper.FromArgb(...) is a 'methode' but is used like a 'type'.  The part FromArgb has a red waveline.

Comment: Meanwhile I created a simple Windows Phone App without Silverlight. 
Here I can set the background for a ReadOnly TextBox.
But (for me) it  is not possible in Windows Phone Silverlight.
Very strange.